# Gradle project refresh failed after AndroidStudio update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I built some android projects with android studio 1.4. Today my computer broke and I reinstalled my operating system . I installed android studio 1.5,but it didn't work with the old projects.I built some new projects and there's no errors.When I open the old projects,there is an error.

Error:Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

I can't find any information about this error,how can I deal with the old projects?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oytbx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your main build.gridle file, may be it trying to use latest gradle and you have used older one in your previous projects.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: This code was already in the build.gradle . and the code of mine is as same as yours. I find that the code in my new project is gradle:1.5.0.So I tried to change 1.3.0 to 1.5.0,but it still doesn't work.This error seems to be about network?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.Just changed the information in gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties->distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
 to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip.And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a network restriction at my production environment that causes this issue.

I solved the same problem by downloading a Gradle version manually and use this local deployment directly:

1. Downloading a proper Gradle version from Gradle site. In my case `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip`
2. Placing this zip file in a proper disk folder, say `/path/to/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip`
3. Editing `projRoot > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties`, so that

```sh
distributionUrl=file:///path/to/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip
```

A robust and cross-platform setup would be

```sh
distributionUrl=gradle-6.4.1-all.zip
```

This is a relative path to

```sh
project_root/android/gradle/wrapper/
```

So you must copy the Gradle zip ball there.